# Div is moved without using any padding or margin

Tags: html, css, next.js

I have a Next.JS application in which I have a div. I want this div to start at the very top of the page. I have padding and margin for the body, HTML and the div itself set to 0 and yet, it's moved a bit down. I checked every single component, none have padding or margin on them. I don't know what is causing it.
[image: Devtools on the body itself]

[image: How it looks by default]

This is the code in my return statement

```
   <div>
      <Head>
         <title>{book.title}</title>
         <meta name="description" content={book.description} />
         <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&family=Tinos&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

      

      <div className="wall">
         <div className="wallContent">
            <h1>{book.title}</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
)
```

This is CSS in global

````
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  background-color: #217934;

}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wall {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60vh;
  background-color: #FFF0D9;
}

.wallContent {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  color: #FF5C5C;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}```

Any help on why it's moved is appreciated!
````

Comment: What is this `div` you have above Head?

Comment: that's a wrapper div you use in next.js.

Comment: Where is the `body`? You cannot have tags out of body tag.

Comment: The margin on the `h1` is collapsing through the div's border. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

there are different ways to solve this but iam not sure if its what you want. first one is with float , second is with position

```js
   .wall {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 60vh;
            background-color: #FFF0D9;
          }
```

```js
     .wall {
            float: left;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 60vh;
            background-color: #FFF0D9;
          }
```

Comment: right, so while this does work. I am interested in knowing why it doesn't do this automatically, since it should and it works fine on other pages (content being right at the top of the page)